# responsive image in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make image responsive using React but cannot make image responsive

```
<img src="url" alt="abc" height="auto" width="40%" id="image-section"/>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
#image-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is more control over the image's responsiveness, try adding a max-width and min-width to a div surrounding your image.

```
<div class="imgBox">
  <img src="url" alt="abc" height="auto" width="40%" id="image-section"/>
<div>
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){

#image-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  };

.imgBox{
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 200px;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I have changed the breakpoint to `600px` to make it easier to view.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-width: 0.1rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .item {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the solution is in adding the `only` to the media query.

Your current query: `@media screen and (max-width: 320px)`

Validates that it is either a screen or max-width: 320px (goes for older browsers, newer do this well).

Solution is to add `only`:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 320px)`

The longer answer can be found here: https://medium.com/@oberoirahul537/difference-between-media-only-and-media-screen-css-queries-c9d42666f861